# How to change font size of \ref

Tags: cross-referencing, fontsize

How can I change the fontsize of a reference mark? My reference is something like:

```
this is a text \ref{figure1}
```

When compiled I get

> this is a text 1

The "1" is in normal font size. How can I change the look of "1" to a smaller font size?

Comment: Do you really want to make it smaller or do you actually want [oldstyle figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an option that works with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{hyperref,letltxmacro}
\newcommand{\reffont}{\small}% References will be \small
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\oldref\ref% Capture \ref in \oldref
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{% Update \ref to use...
  {\reffont\oldref{#1}}}% ...\reffont
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{This is a figure}\label{figure}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{figure}.
\end{document}
```

If `hyperref` is used, reference updating is (should be) delayed until the beginning of the document. If not, then a redefinition can be done earlier.

You can redefine `\reffont` at will to obtain a different font size (or style) of your reference.

Answer (score 4):

How about changing the fonts to, say, `Palatino` with the option `[osf]` (oldstyle figures)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo} % changes font to Palatino

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  % <codes>
  \caption{Some figure}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

This is Figure \ref{fig:1}.

\end{document}
```